# Magento 1.9.3.2 edit table /email/order/items.phtml - Solved

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, items

I can not change  `<th>` and color in email order

I changed the file /email/order/items.phtml but it does not work

If I add another `<th>`not work

Instead it works if I change the file in /email/order/items/default.phtml

Thanks

[image: change th inside items.phtml]

Comment: Please provide relative paths from Magento root, eg. `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/default.phtml`. 
Is there any extension overriding/extending any of core email functionalities?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the base template with path /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml, the problem is not the default.phtml file

default.phtml works

Comment: The file **blod**/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml **bold** that contains the header of the table even though the modifier does not change anything

Comment: Yes I use OneStepCheckout and Abandoned Cart, maybe one of these changes the core.

Comment: @versedi thanks ... you were right, onestepcheckout rewrote the base

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

@versedi thanks

My extension OneStepCheckout rewrote the core base

Comment: If you've answered the question yourself you can still mark it as an accepted answer.